# why is my object becoming null, and how should I address this?

Tags: flash, object, actionscript, null

Alright within this code:

```
package GameFiles.SourceCode.Classes
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;

public class User extends MovieClip
{
    private var numStars:int = 65;
    public static var enemyList:Array = new Array();
    private var ourShip:Ship;
    private var scoreHUD:ScoreHUD;

    public function User() : void
    {

        var ourShip:Ship = new Ship(stage);
        stage.addChild(ourShip);

        ourShip.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        ourShip.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        ourShip.addEventListener("hit", shipHit, false, 0, true);
        scoreHUD = new ScoreHUD(stage);
        stage.addChild(scoreHUD);

        for (var i:int = 0; i < numStars; i++)
        {
            stage.addChildAt(new Star(stage), stage.getChildIndex(ourShip));
        }

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);

    }
    private function loop(e:Event) : void
    {
        if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 90) <= scoreHUD.s_score / 100)
        {
            var enemy:Astroid = new Astroid(stage, ourShip);
            enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeEnemy, false, 0, true);
            enemyList.push(enemy);
            enemy.addEventListener("Passed", enemyPassed, false, 0, true);
            stage.addChild(enemy);              
        }
    }
    public function shipHit(e:Event) : void
    {
        scoreHUD.updateHits(e.currentTarget.points);
        ourShip.updateHitCount(1);
    }
    public function enemyPassed(e:Event) : void
    {
        scoreHUD.updateScore(10);
    }

    private function removeEnemy(e:Event)
    {
        enemyList.splice(enemyList.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1);
    }   
}   
}
```

The variable `ourShip` is defined as object ship (I can trace this for a majority of the code) and yet when I reach the `shipHit` function and try to reference `ourShip` to adjust a variable within my ship class it says that it is null and I get an error.  I don't understand why it became null, and that particular part of the code as I see it is the optimal place to update the variable. I am already updating a similar variable within `scoreHUD`.

Comment: tried to, I need to work on my rep more before I can add such a fancy tag :)

Answer (score 0):

Few tips:

change

```
public static var enemyList:Array = new Array();
```

to

```
public static var enemyList:Array = [];
```

works the same, but faster.

Second, I see no reason for you to use weak reference in your listener:

```
ourShip.addEventListener("hit", shipHit, false, 0, true);
```

change to just:

```
ourShip.addEventListener("hit", shipHit);
```

same with the other listeners you add (FRAME_ENTER).
Weak reference in the listener just simply means that your listener is going to be removed when the garbage collector runs so you don't have any memory taken by unused objects. Also, if the object has at least one active listener it can't be removed.

So you create a large amount of stars, the memory is taken, you app runs a few cycles and the Flash Player decides to do a garbage collection run, cleans all the weak listeners and you have pointers to null object references.

That's my guess, remove the weak reference and see what happens ;)

Comment: I suppose I don't yet fully understand the complete difference between weak and strong references.  I thought a weak reference was something along the lines of var x; (without giving it further information like int, number, string or whatnot, didn't know it extended to event listeners also, so clearly this is something I need to read up on more.  But I did try to implement those changes and am receiving the same error at the same spot, ourShip has become null somewhere/somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I would change this line (inside your constructor):

```
var ourShip:Ship = new Ship(stage);
```

to

```
ourShip = new Ship(stage);
```

I believe that's creating local scope instance of ourShip that won't exist outside of the constructor function.